# Why can't you import now() from the datetime module?

Tags: python, datetime, import

I skimmed over the datetime.py file and it does have a now() method/function and I thought import was used to include specific methods and variables.

Answer (score 6):

[`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) is actually a method of the **class** `datetime` that you can import from the **module** `datetime`.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
```

Comment: @tripleee: you can't import class methods (unless these are the attributes of a module object and `datetime.datetime` is not a module).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Indeed, I was quite surprising it could work but I tried and of course it failed.

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime

print datetime # <module 'datetime' (built-in)>

print datetime.datetime # <type 'datetime.datetime'>

print datetime.datetime.now # <built-in method now of type object at 0x00000000701B9300>

print datetime.datetime.now() # 2016-01-11 14:07:23.763000
```

**datetime** is the module, which is actually nothing more than a python file that includes classes.

**datetime.datetime** is a class defined in that python file.

**datetime.datetime.now** is a method defined in that class. So it is not importable without actually importing the class.

and finally **datetime.datetime.now()** is the method called to return the value.

Answer (score 2):

`now()` is a method of the `datetime` class:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 15, 8, 22, 634020)
```

If you want just use now you could do following:

```
now = datetime.now
print(now())
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 15, 9, 24, 683569)
```